# f.select helper - how to pass value other than id

Tags: ruby, select, field, helper

I have this code:

```
<%= f.label :lang  %><br />
<%= f.select :lang_id, @langs %>
```

it generates html like that:

```
<label for="entry_lang">Lang</label><br /> 
<select id="entry_lang_id" name="entry[lang_id]">
  <option value="pl">1</option>
  <option value="en">2</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to have "pl" and "en" visible for user, not integers. So I tried:

```
<%= f.label :lang  %><br />
<%= f.select :lang_name, @langs %>
```

And it doesn't work. How to do it right?

Comment: Is this Ruby, or Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your @langs array is in the format:

```
[[1, "pl"], [2, "en"], ....]
```

It should be the other way around; display name first, then id:

```
[["pl", 1], ["en", 2], ....]
```